# How to extract a list of users with rights to create domain users in the Active Directory?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, administrator

I was tasked with creating Powershell scripts that we will use to review the Active Directory of our clients. I like to add that my knowledge of Powershell is very basic, but I've found A LOT online (including many Stack Overflow topics!) to help me with this task. My script is pretty much in place, but there is one functionality that I would like to add to my script. I do not know if (and how) this even possible. I've looked at many sites to help me with this issue, but I did not find any solutions. So I decided to ask it to the community itself. Here is a description of my issue.

What I want is to have a list of users that have the rights to create Domain Users and have the rights to install Updates / Hot-Fixes on Domain Controllers. In order to be able to create a Domain User, the user must have a membership (or equivalent) to Domain Administrators (Found here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd894463(v=ws.10).aspx. It's easy to get the Domain Administrators and Enterprise Administrators (the latter having also the ability to create Domain Users obviously). I have a script that retrieves all the Domain Users and the groups that they have membership to, so that is covered.

What I want to achieve is to get Domain Users that are not a member of the Domain Administrators (or equivalent) groups that have rights to create Domain Users (or within certain OU's like explained in this topic https://serverfault.com/questions/83686/how-to-create-a-limited-domain-admin-that-does-not-have-access-to-domain-contr).

There is not an attribute that defines what I am looking for. I had some ideas of using de 'admincount' property like this: `Get-ADUser -Server $ADServer -Filter {admincount -gt 0}`. This returns to me all the ADUsers that are within the Default Protected Groups within the Active Directory. But what I want is to be able to get Users that are not contained in these groups.

Is there a way to get this information?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I began fully coding this but without seeing your script and not having a full test AD env in front of me at the moment, I will give you the psudo-code as it seems like you've done enough that you can probably take this code and run with it and pretty easily have a fully working script since most the primary commands/filters needed I have included below:

Get a list of all OUs

```
$OUs = @(Get-ADDomain | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName)
$OUs += Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
$OUs += Get-ADObject -SearchBase (Get-ADDomain).DistinguishedName -SearchScope OneLevel -LDAPFilter '(objectClass=container)' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
```

Get a filtered list of all non-admin users using:

```
Get-ADUser -Server $ADServer -Filter { admincount -eq 0 }
```

Loop through each of the OUs and retrieve their permissions

```
foreach ($OU in $OUs)
(Get-Acl $OU).access | where { accesscontroltype -eq 'Allow' })
```

Inner loop your filtered non-admin user array with each access permission needed to perform the pseudo-admin duties using:

```
foreach ($objUser in $(Get-ADUser -Server $ADServer -Filter { admincount -eq 0 }))
(Get-Acl $OU).access | where { identityreference -eq <TRIMMED INNER LOOP USER OBJECT NAME FROM $objUser> }
```

If matched, add to new array, otherwise do nothing

Dump array to report

Comment: Getting a list of all OUs was easy with the commands you've provided. However the rest dit not really work. Here is an explanation of what went wrong: When using the cmdlet `Get-ADUser -Server $ADServer -Filter { admincount -eq 0 }` I get no results. I've also tried changing it to things like '-ne 1' , '-lt 1' , '-eq <not set>' (<not set> is the defualt parameter of the admincount property). None of these cmdlets got me a list of all non-admin users. The admincount property is automaticly set by the system every 15 minutes. So I have to find a workaround for this.

Comment: I've changed the loop you've provided to the following: `foreach ($OU in $OUs){((Get-Acl).access | where { accesscontroltype -eq 'Allow' })}`. But this code miraculously doesn't accept 'accesscontroltype' term and says it is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet. I can't define a logical explanation why it doesn't.  The last piece i have not been able to try out, hence these two are not working properly.